# Tracking OpenVPN user login

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, openvpn

Situatio is that each user login is loged in log file. Each Server start log file is erased and created new. Is any way to log user logins into antoher file or other place that when server start it won't destroy records?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `--client-connect` directive in your `server.conf`

This directives allows you to specify a script to run when a client has just been authenticated.
The script called by this directive will retrieve some environmental variables set by openvpn server for the authenticated user, such as : Common Name (`$common_name`) and IP address (`$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip`)

Your directive should look like this :

```
client-connect /path/to/your/script.sh
```

And the `script.sh` :

```
#!/bin/sh

user=$common_name
remote_ip=$trusted_ip
local_ip=$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip

echo $(date) $user $remote_ip $local_ip >>/path/to/your/logfile.log
```

Directive `--client-disconnect` exists also, in case you want to trace when clients disconnect.

More infos on this can be found here :
https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html

Comment: Don't forget to add the script-security in the config 

--script-security {0,1,2,3} (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man8/openvpn.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

1. Enable executing scripts in the OpenVPN configuration (the `script-level` directive, IIRC).
2. Make a script which logs the Canonical Name (CN) from the certificate presented by the authenticated client to a file or sends it to whatever other event registeration system.